# NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, security, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have generated self signed certificate for my server. After importing root CA cert to my browser, I was trying to access my website via Chrome, I am however getting "NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" error. Is there a way to 'debug' Chrome's certs procedure so that I could find out what I am doing wrong when generating the cert ?

The error is very vague and makes me run in circles tweaking portions of the script I wrote to make it work ... without luck.

Here is the script (I have changed certs subject details for security purposes ;-) )

```
echo "Removing existing files ..."
rm root*
rm server*
rm v3*

echo "Step 1"
printf "  authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer\n  basicConstraints=CA:FALSE\n  
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, 
dataEncipherment\n  subjectAltName = @alt_names\n\n  [alt_names]\n  IP.1 = 
"$1 > v3.ext

echo "Step 2"
openssl genrsa -out rootCA.key 2048

echo "Step 3"
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out 
rootCA.pem -subj 
"/C=US/ST=PA/L=Pittsburgh/O=TestTest/OU=TestTest/CN=www.test.com"

echo "Step 4"
openssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -out server.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout 
server.key -subj "/C=US/ST=PA/L=Pittsburgh/O=ServerCert/OU=ServerCert/CN=$1"

echo "Step 5"
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -
CAcreateserial -out server.pem -days 500 -sha256 -extfile v3.ext
```

IE uses the same repository for root certificates as Chrome, but it does validate my cert successfully.

Comment: You create a CA (step 3) and a CSR (step 4). There is no server certificate created from the CSR (issued by the CA). What do you use as your server certificate? And, you might just follow existing guides like https://gist.github.com/Soarez/9688998 or https://liuhongjiang.github.io/hexotech/2016/12/23/setup-your-own-ca/

Comment: Hi, I am sorry, I forgot to copy over STEP 5 from the script.